# Facebook setAutoGrow() with jQuery - page height decrease

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm working at building a facebook page tab that displays several lists of information. Each section is a bit lengthy, so I'd like to use the jQuery toggle command to show/hide each section.

I've successfully implemented the new setAutoGrow() for when height increases, but I haven't quite ironed out how to use it when the page shrinks (or when a div is hidden again). The page height remains the same with a lot of white space below. I realize the setAutoGrow function natively doesn't do that, but I tried using the following timeout to no avail. What am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.fbAsyncInit = function sizeChangeCallback() {
FB.Canvas.setSize({height:800});
setTimeout("FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()",500);}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.facebook_headline').click(function() {
    $('.facebook_list').toggle('slow', sizeChangeCallback())
    return false;
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: My first note would be ... setAutoGrow() ='s utter rubbish. otherwise does auto grow work when you make things smaller? I'd read facebooks documentation on it.

Comment: The best solution in market is: http://www.twistermc.com/36764/shrink-facebook-tabs/#comment-626723 Works like a charm..